# Make animation work before changing view Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, animation

I have some questions. I'm a total novice to Objective-c and Xcode's development.

My problem is the following:
I have a button with an IBActions (cambia view) and an Outlet (gioca_outlet).
This button is connected to another view by the "Show", so when I press the next view appears.

But, before changing view I'd like to commit animations with the button, which has its own image.

I'd like to scale the button's image size (maintaining the same center) for 1/2 seconds, then show the second view.
I'd also like the button's size to be the initial one when I skip back to the main view.

So, I came up with this code:

```
    - (IBAction)cambiaview:(id)sender {

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.4 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:{
 [_gioca_outlet setCenter:CGPointMake([_gioca_outlet.center].x + 0.0001, [_gioca_outlet.center].y +0.0001)];
 [_gioca_outlet setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(_gioca_outlet.transform, 2.0, 2.0)];}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 };
}
```

Back button, to return to the main view:

```
      - (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
              [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ //
               }];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you exactly want? After pressing the button, the button's image will be bigger and then the second view appears and when you come back to the first view, then the size of the button should remain same as it was in the beginnig? Please confirm so that I can help you. @cristakey

Comment: Yes, moreover, when clicking the button an audio file should start.

Comment: How large is your audio file?

Comment: It's only 2,28 seconds long and its size is 548kb

Answer (score 0):

Open Interface Builder and delete all existing connections between two view controllers.

Then ctrl+drag from first view controller to the second and choose "Show" option.
[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xoxl.png)

After that click on the created connection (it's called segue), switch to Attributes Inspector and give it an ID [step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2AGj.png)

In the completion block of your animation write `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showNextView"];`

Answer (score 0):

You have connected the `button`'s action segue with the second view, so as soon as you clicked on the button, next view appears. Instead, you connect a segue from `viewcontroller1`  to `viewcontroller2` and give an identifier to your `segue`.

Then on `button`'s click event, add this code.

```
- (IBAction)cambiaview:(id)sender
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
        //this will transform your button to grow a little bit bigger
        _gioca_outlet.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //push from viewcontroller1 to viewcontroller2 using you segue identifier
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"vc1tovc2segue" sender:self]
    }];
```

This code will make your button a little bit bigger animatedly and then pushes to second view controller.

Now, if you want to play an audio, you can play it in second view controller's `viewDidLoad` method using `AVFoundation` framework.

To play the sound file do the following:

1. Add your sound file in your projects directory.
2. Import `AVFoundation` framework by writing,

   ```
    #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
   ```
3. Create a strong property of `AVAudioPlayer` in .h of your `viewcontroller2`.

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;
   ```
4. Then in `viewcontroller2`'s `viewDidLoad` add this code to play the audio file,

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       //SampleAudio is your audio file name and mp3 is your extension.
       NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SampleAudio"  ofType:@"mp3"];
       NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

       self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
       self.player.delegate = self;

       [self.player play];
   }
   ```

To make the button's size normal when you come back to your first view controller, add this code in your first view controller:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    _gioca_outlet.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

Hope this helps. 
If you face any problem understanding anything, feel free to leave a comment. :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it works for the audio file but when I press the button the animation doesn't commit. 
The view changes to the second, but the button doesn't slowly grow.
Only when I turn back to the main page, I can see my new big button.
I'd like the button to have the original when I switch to main view.
Thanks for you help

Comment: Edited my question. Set the button's transfrom 1.5 instead of 1.25 and UIView animation timing 0.8  from 0.3. @cristakeyIT

Comment: Thanks again, sorry if I insist but it doesn't work. I mean, it doesn't grow gradually, I can't see any alteration of the size when clicking on it.
I was told not to make this animation but I'd like to know what is the mistake

Comment: do you have any background color or any image of your button? If not then you can't see the animation. Try giving a background color or an image to your button, then you can see the animation. @cristakeyIT

Comment: I didn't know. Thanks! I'll get a try